# Open Refreigerator door trips other breakers

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a breaker problem. Opening door(s) on our whirlpool refrigerator randomly (maybe once or twice per month) trips OTHER breakers in the house (usually same one but for an adjacent room) trip. Those breakers have the test button on them. They are not adjacent breakers in the panel.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel, and what model is your fridge for that matter?

Comment: What wiring method is used in your place? Conduit /Romex?  Could you post a photo of the breakers in question?

Answer (score 1):

They don't have to be adjacent to be a MWBC sharing a neutral, just on different legs and without handle ties. Handle ties were not always required. Fridge's have been known to trip GFCI breakers. Try switching it to a non GFCI. Why is the adjacent room on a GFCI?  If possible try a regular breaker on that room too.

Comment: I'm suspecting this is an AFCI issue, not GFCI...which means it could be something a bit weirder

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Weirder would fit right in for some of the stuff we've seen here. :-)

Comment: Commons tied can also cause strange things.